# Transpose of the Hilbert-Schmidt operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, compact-operators

Let $X = L^2(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open set (or a $\sigma$-finite measure space), $B \in L^2( \Omega \times \Omega)$. Then the *Hilbert-Schmidt operator* $T \in \mathcal L(X)$ defined by $Tf(x) = \int_\Omega B(x,y) f(y) \mbox{d}y$ is known to be compact. I would like to find its transpose $T'$, $T' \in \mathcal L(X')$, and show that it is compact too.

The last is easy: $T'$ is compact by Schauder' theorem, since $T$ is compact. The first part is more difficult. I know that $L^2$ is a Hilbert space and moreover $L^2$ is isomorphic to its dual $(L^2)'$ as a special case of the Riesz' theorem, then $T'$ coincide with the adjoint $T^*$, but at this point of the lecture notes Hilbert spaces framework has not been introduced yet. Furthermore, I know the solution (for example, Yosida pp 197-198), i.e. $(T^*g)(y) = \int_\Omega \overline{B(y,x)} g(x) \, \mbox{d}x$. This is my reasoning:

By definition of dual operator adapted to this case, $\langle T' F, f \rangle_{X' X} = \langle F, Tf \rangle_{X' X} $, so $T' F (f) = F(T_f)$. $F \in (L^2)'$ is represented via Riesz' theorem as

\begin{equation}
F_g (f) = \int_\Omega g(x) f(x) \, \mbox{d}x,
\end{equation}

for all $f \in L^2$ and where $g \in L^2$. Hence

\begin{equation}
F_g (Tf) = \int_\Omega g(x) \int_\Omega B(x,y)f(y) \, \mbox{d}y \, \mbox{d}x .
\end{equation}

Since $g(x)$ does not depend on $y$, with an application of Fubini-Tonelli theorem we can write

\begin{equation}
F_g (Tf) = \int_\Omega \int_\Omega g(x) B(x,y)f(y)\,\mbox{d}x \, \mbox{d}y = T' F (f).
\end{equation}

Now, I'm stuck. How to achieve the conclusion? And what is wrong? (maybe would be easier "what is correct?")

**Notation.** $F \in X'$ is a functional. I dropped dependencies on variables when not necessary, e.g $F_g( Tf )$ is a shorthand for $F_g( Tf (x) )$.

Comment: Am I missing something? I'd think you Fubini-Tonelli again, and $$F_g(Tf) = \int_\Omega \left(\int_\Omega g(x)B(x,y)\,dx\right)f(y)\,dy = T'F_g(f),$$ so $T'(\langle g\mid\cdot\,\rangle) = \langle\int B(x,\,\cdot\,)g(x)\,dx\mid \,\cdot\,\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, I thought this but I didn't write, since my main trouble is the passage $B(x,y) \to \overline{B(y,x)}$ (I have the feeling that is a very silly thing, but it just won't come out).

Comment: For the conjugation, you'd be working with complex scalars, and then you'd have $F_g(f) = \int_\Omega \overline{g(x)}f(x)\,dx$. And that gives you $$F_g(Tf) = \int_\Omega \left(\overline{\int_\Omega g(x)\overline{B(x,y)}\,dx}\right)f(y)\,dy.$$ It seems somebody has accidentally swapped the variables in $B(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,)$ for $T'$, however.

Comment: Oh, many thanks! It was all day I was reasoning about that! For the swapping maybe a typo in Yosida's book?

Comment: Yes, definitely a typo in Yosida. Note he writes "... defined by $(K^\ast y)(t) = \int_a^b \overline{K(t,s)}\,y(s)\,ds$. Hence $K$ is self-adjoint iff $K(s,t) = \overline{K(t,s)}$ for a.e. $s,t$." The latter characterisation of self-adjointness is correct (compare with matrices), but that means we have $(K^\ast y)(s) = \int_a^b \overline{K(t,s)}\,y(t)\,dt$. [Note the changes in $s,t$]